# Couldn't calculate value of volume on basis of values from the same object nested in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I am making a react app, it has button Add to add a new calculation which consists of 2 input fields (to input thickness and surface), Volume to output a result of multiplication and button "X" to remove the current line from the screen.
I managed to get data from input and put inside object array. But I can't calculate value of volume on basis of inputted values. Could someone help me, please. Thank you.
Error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'thickness' of undefined
(anonymous function)
src/App.js:22
  19 |   let newArr = [...datas];
  20 |   newArr[index] = {
  21 |     ...newArr[index],
> 22 |     volume: (this.thickness * this.surface) / 1000,
     | ^  23 |   };
  24 |   setDatas(newArr);
  25 | }
View compiled
▶ 19 stack frames were collapsed.
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.  Click the 'X' or hit ESC to dismiss this message.
```

My code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
const App = () => {
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (index) => (event) => {
    const index = event.target.id;
    if (event.target.name === "thickness") {
      let newArr = [...datas];
      newArr[index] = { ...newArr[index], thickness: +event.target.value };
      setDatas(newArr);
    }
    if (event.target.name === "surface") {
      let newArr = [...datas];
      newArr[index] = { ...newArr[index], surface: +event.target.value };
      setDatas(newArr);
    }

    if (datas[index].thickness && datas[index].surface) {
      let newArr = [...datas];
      newArr[index] = {
        ...newArr[index],
        volume: (this.thickness * this.surface) / 1000,
      };
      setDatas(newArr);
    }
  };

  const removeItem = (index) => {
    let newItems = datas.filter((product, id) => id !== index);
    setDatas(newItems);
  };
  console.log(datas);
  return (
    <>
      {datas.map((data, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={index}>
            <input
              label="thickness mm"
              name="thickness"
              id={index}
              value={data.thickness}
              onChange={handleChange(index)}
            />
            <input
              name="surface"
              label="surface m¬2"
              id={index}
              value={data.surface}
              onChange={handleChange(index)}
            />
            <span>Volume {data.volume}</span>
            <button onClick={() => removeItem(index)}>X</button>
          </li>
        );
      })}

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setDatas([
            ...datas,
            {
              thickness: 0,
              surface: 0,
              volume: 0,
            },
          ]);
        }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Functional components don't have a `this`.

Comment: replacing `this` with `newArr[index]` should do the trick

Comment: Thank you. I replaced it, but it is not work as expected because I can't input more than 1 symbol in the second input field. Probably do you know the solution to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the React functional components, the `this` keyword will not work. Try remove it.

Comment: Thank you. I replaced it, but it is not work as expected because I can't input more than 1 symbol in the second input field. Probably do you know the solution to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. I changed the handleChange  and it works.

```
        const handleChange = (index) => (event) => {
    if (event.target.name === "thickness") {
      let newArr = [...datas];
      newArr[index] = { ...newArr[index], thickness: +event.target.value };

      if (datas[index].thickness && datas[index].surface) {
        newArr[index] = {
          ...newArr[index],
          volume: (+event.target.value * newArr[index].surface) / 1000,
        };
      }
      setDatas(newArr);
    }
    if (event.target.name === "surface") {
      let newArr = [...datas];
      newArr[index] = { ...newArr[index], surface: +event.target.value };
      if (datas[index].thickness && datas[index].surface) {
        newArr[index] = {
          ...newArr[index],
          volume: (newArr[index].thickness * +event.target.value) / 1000,
        };
      }
      setDatas(newArr);
    }
  };
```